# Populating ListFragment from JSON

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-listfragment, android-loader

I've an Activity that extends ActionBarActivity and implements ActionBar.Listener.
It's acting like a View Pager. Inside that I have 3 ListFragment (organized in 3 tabs).
Now, I need to populate fragments with data from a back end.
Could you help me to organize code structure?

1. Should I use AsyncTask or a Loader? Is it better to put them in a separate public class?
2. Is it a good idea using retained fragments to preserve data through tabs swipe and
   configuration changes?
3. The result I've in mind is a big loader image, placed in the center of the fragment waiting
   for data. After a while it disappears and shows records inside ListFragment rows. Where should I put
   the call to the AsyncTask (assuming use of this class)? In activity? Inside each fragment?
4. Which is the correct way to communicate to fragment that activity is calling onPostExecute and data are ready for use?

I'm quite confused about that, I just need a good way to start, it seems that everyone is approching
this in a different way and I don't know which is the best...

Comment: Retaining is an easy method of doing such, however, I was told - but never verified, that retaining should be avoided because "Android seems to discourage retaining..."; not sure why though. Even so, if your activity is destroyed to free needed memory - retained frags are destroyed anyway. Fragments, when retained, are only kept alive when an activity is destroyed for a configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

I've used json to populate a `listfragment` like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lista_ordens, null);
    context = inflater.getContext();
    ordemServicoLista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    }
```

Here i execute the method to call webService and put all information in a listAdapter:

```
    new CarregaOrdens().execute();
    setListAdapter(adapterListaOrdens);
```